# make install error 'nothing to be done'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

make install in ubuntu  giving me following error please help

```
Making install in src 
make[1]: Entering directory /home/miracle/rnnlib_source_forge_version/src'
make[2]: Entering directory /home/miracle/rnnlib_source_forge_version/src'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
 /usr/bin/install -c '../bin/rnnlib' '/usr/local/bin/rnnlib'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for install-data-am'`
make[2]: Leaving directory /home/miracle/rnnlib_source_forge_version/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory /home/miracle/rnnlib_source_forge_version/src'
make[1]: Entering directory /home/miracle/rnnlib_source_forge_version'
make[2]: Entering directory /home/miracle/rnnlib_source_forge_version'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory /home/miracle/rnnlib_source_forge_version'
make[1]: Leaving directory /home/miracle/rnnlib_source_forge_version'
```

Comment: You're not giving us very much to go on here. Why do you think this is an error?

Answer (score 4):

'nothing to be done' need not be bad news. It just means that there is nothing to be done for that specific part (maybe because of your system specs or the arguments you passed to configure or whatever). Did you actually see if the programs run after doing make install?
You'll probably have to do something like

> ./configure --prefix=/usr

to get a lot of the things working.

---

OR

---

Try one of the following methods, for I replied

1. login as root user -> # then "make" and "make install"
2. For more configuration details run

> $ ./configure --help

Answer (score 0):

try to compile it again with a new configure or look at the options by typing:

```
./configure --help
```

After compiling: try to "make" it again.