# E: Unable to locate package virtuoso-vad-cartridges while installing Virtuoso

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, virtuoso, rdfstore, openlink-virtuoso

I am trying to install openlink vituoso
Inserting below command in ubuntu 16.04,

**sudo apt-get install virtuoso-vad-{isparql,ods,cartridges,tutorial}**

I have following messages:

*Reading package lists... Done*
*Building dependency tree*

*Reading state information... Done*

***E: Unable to locate package virtuoso-vad-cartridges***

nothing happens when I do
**apt-cache search virtuoso-vad-cartridges**

no error , no result!

I have also done 
"*sudo apt-get update*"

and still have the problem

How can I do "*sudo apt-get install virtuoso-vad-{isparql,ods,cartridges,tutorial}*" without errors?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [the Virtuoso documentation notes for Ubuntu deployment](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSUbuntuNotes#Further%20VAD%20Packages) --

> Ubuntu have split some of the Virtuoso VAD packages into separate `apt` packages of their own. When you `apt-get install` these, all you get is the VAD package on disk ready to be installed into your database; Ubuntu does not install the VAD into any running instance for you (because by this time you might have created your own instances elsewhere on different ports).

That being the case, I would suggest you simply download the VAD packages directly from our download site.  You didn't not indicate which version of Virtuoso is being installed, and Ubuntu packaging has historically been some months or even years behind our updates.  Guessing you're working with Virtuoso 7.2, please [start here](http://download3.openlinksw.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-vos-packages/7.2/).  Please comment below if you need the VADs for a different version of Virtuoso (7.1, 6.x, 8.x, etc.).

For further assistance with Virtuoso Open Source (VOS), I strongly recommend the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/).

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)

Comment: I tried to install it based on tutorial: "_https://www.openlinksw.com/vos/main/VOS/VOSUbuntuNotes_"   and  when I do "**sudo aptitude install  virtuoso-opensource**" it automatically installs "version (6.1.6+repack-0ubuntu5)
" so I think I need the VADs for 6.x version. Please let me know if there is a better step by step tutorial for installing the latest available version of virtuoso Thank you so much

Comment: As I said, Ubuntu packaging lags. To get the latest and greatest (which is *strongly* recommended), you'll have to [build from source](https://www.openlinksw.com/vos/main/VOS/VOSUbuntuNotes#Building%20from%20Upstream%20Source). To keep working with that long-outdated VOS 6.1.6, you can [download suitable VADs here](http://download3.openlinksw.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-packages/6.4/virtuoso/)

Comment: Thank you so much but I went through the steps in"Build from source" and I have below error after "**sudo make install**":  make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'. In which step should I install the VAD packages? After **Sudo make install**?

Comment: Please see [make install error 'nothing to be done'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937345/make-install-error-nothing-to-be-done). If that's insufficient, I'm sorry, but this kind of back-and-forth is not appropriate for this site. Please bring this to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), where Virtuoso developers, fellow users, and others can assist you.